# Downloading other users files on Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have tried to download my from Ubuntu One web interface (download all my files as .zip) but I got the file of another user! When browsing I see my files but at download thefiles are not mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You quite obviously shouldn't receive anyone files but your own, this is not only a nuisance to you, but a security issue to that other user.

Double-check who you are logged in as. Double-check the contents (e.g. that you didn't have a bunch of backups or files from a share that you forgot about) and if it isn't an error on your part along either of those lines, then contact U1 support immediately.

Comment: I browse a folder then I click on download all as a zip then when I look to the downloaded zip file the files are not mine.

Comment: That definitely sounds like you need to contact Ubuntu One about it.

Comment: I have done it.